# How do you restrict sideway movement in 3D endless runner in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I have been making a endless runner 3d game and implemented 3 lane side way movement. It's working perfectly, although I want to restrict my movement for the 3 lanes only. If my character for example say on left lane, If I press left again it should not move to the side anymore since there's not lane beyond the left one. I did implemented a logic for this, though when I press either left or right in the borders of the lanes it freezes the side way movement. Any idea on how to stop this. This is my code.

PlayerMortor.cs

```
     private bool isChangingLane = false;
     private Vector3 locationAfterChanginLane = Vector3.zero;
     private Vector3 sideWayMovementDistance = Vector3.right * 2f;
     private float sideWaySpeed = 6f;

     void Update()
        {
            currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);    

            if (controller.isGrounded)
            {
                verticalVelocity = -0.5f;
                if (currentBaseState.fullPathHash == locoState)
                {
                    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                    {
                        verticalVelocity = 18f;

                        anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
                    } 
                }

                MoveLeftRight(); //Call sideway movement on update()

                if (isChangingLane)
                {
                    if (Math.Abs(transform.position.x - locationAfterChanginLane.x) < 0.1f)
                    {
                        isChangingLane = false;
                        moveVector.x = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
       }

    private void MoveLeftRight() //Sideway Movement function
    {
        if (controller.isGrounded && !isChangingLane)
        {
            isChangingLane = true;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
            {
                locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position - sideWayMovementDistance;
                moveVector.x = -sideWaySpeed;
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
            {
                locationAfterChanginLane = transform.position + sideWayMovementDistance;
                moveVector.x = +sideWaySpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit) //Restriction when we move sideways beyond border
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Border")
        {
            Debug.Log("Border Hit");
            isChangingLane = false;
            moveVector.x = 0;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine it as a simple state machine.

[image]

Keep track of your current state, and when you get an incoming state change request (the key presses), compare it to the current state to see what you should do.

```
//At the top of your script
public enum Lane {Left, Center, Right}
public enum MoveDirection {Left, Right, None}

Lane currentLane = Lane.Center;

//In the update method
MoveDirection requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.None;
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) {
    requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.Left;
} else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D)) {
    requestedMoveDirection = MoveDirection.Right;
}
switch(requestedMoveDirection) {
    case MoveDirection.Right: 
        if(currentLane == Lane.Right) {
           break; //Do nothing when in right lane
        } else if(currentLane == Lane.Center) {
           MoveRight();
           currentLane = Lane.Right;
        } else if (currentLane == Lane.Left) {
           MoveRight();
           currentLane = Lane.Center;
        }
        break;
     case MoveDirection.Left:
        if(currentLane == Lane.Left) {
           break; //Do nothing when in left lane
        } else if(currentLane == Lane.Center) {
           MoveLeft();
           currentLane = Lane.Left;
        } else if (currentLane == Lane.Right) {
           MoveLeft();
           currentLane = Lane.Center;
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Great I'll try and implement this to my code. Thanks for the help @Byte56

Comment: I applied your code. Works perfectly. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Vector3.Lerp

Linearly interpolates between two vectors.

Interpolates between the vectors a and b by the interpolant t. The parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]. This is most commonly used to find a point some fraction of the way along a line between two endpoints (e.g. to move an object gradually between those points).

in below script Direction value is limied to the range [-1, 1].so I multiply this value to player's position.z

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public int Direction;

    void Update(){
        Analyze ();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.A)) {
            print ("left");
            if (Direction == 0 || Direction == 1) {
                Direction--;
            }
        } else if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.D)) {
            print ("right");
            if (Direction == 0 || Direction == -1) {
                Direction++;
            }
        }
    }

    void Analyze(){
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, new Vector3 (0, 0, 3 * Direction), 0.1f);
    }
}
```